# Storing info in a client's clipboard like Activestate

Tags: clipboard

[Activestate Code Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/528893-pathcatcher-windows-utility-for-right-click-captur/) has the function of storing information in a clipboard in a client that access the web. How can I do that?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with client. It runs on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store information on the client's clipboard using Javascript.

http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/